# Problems using a Collapse MaterialUI componente inside an iterableble component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im having troubles to expand and contract a [Collapse](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/collapse/) Component from MaterialUI since Im mapping and array and iterating the same component, when i press the collapse button, all components expands/contracts at the same time ( I suppose that Im not providing an identifier to point where the collapse function should be used),Im currently Using an State to control the collapse action:

```
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
```

This is the return where I iterate the component using **map** on *RecetasAll* object,

```
return (
      <React.Fragment key={RecetasAll.id}>
        <Card className="searchItem" sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
          <CardHeader
            action={<IconButton aria-label="settings"></IconButton>}
            title={RecetasAll.titulo}
          />
          <h4
            className="Dieta"
            style={{
              backgroundColor: color(RecetasAll.Tiporeceta.tipoReceta),
            }}
          >
            {RecetasAll.Tiporeceta.tipoReceta}
          </h4>
          <span className="Calorias">{RecetasAll.informacionNutricional}</span>
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            height="194"
            image={RecetasAll.imagen}
            alt="Paella dish"
          />
          <CardContent>
            {RecetasAll.Productos.map((Productos) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={Productos.id}>
                  <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                    {Productos.producto}
                  </Typography>
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            })}
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions disableSpacing>
            <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
              <FavoriteIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <ExpandMore
              expand={expanded}
              onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}
              aria-expanded={expanded}
            >
              <ExpandMoreIcon />
            </ExpandMore>
          </CardActions>
          <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <CardContent id={RecetasAll.id}>
              <Typography paragraph>Preparacion:</Typography>

              <Typography paragraph>{RecetasAll.pasos}</Typography>
              <Button
                href="#contained-buttons"
                variant="contained"
                onClick={handleSearch}
              >
                Ver mas
              </Button>
            </CardContent>
          </Collapse>
        </Card>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
    });

     return <>{itemRecetas}</>;
    }
```

Im triying to set an id property to the [CardContent](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/card-content/) since its the child of the Collapse component

> id={RecetasAll.id}

this is the function Im using to expand or collapse but I dont know how to get the id  properly to compare its value with *expanded* state:

```
  const handleExpandClick = (e) => {
    let clickedItemId = e.currentTarget.id;
    if (expanded === clickedItemId) {
      setExpanded(!expanded);
    } else {
      setExpanded(clickedItemId);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you want every Card to collapse/expand on its own and currently collapsing/expanding one will trigger them all?

Comment: @RubenSmn Yes! Im iterating this component multiple times but need to have individual collapse/expand events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refactor every card into a new component and that way you can have a state to open/close the individual card. When iterating you can pass in the `RecetasAll`.

```js
const MyCard = ({ RecetasAll }) => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);

  const toggleExpanded = () => {
    setIsExpanded(prevIsExpanded => !prevIsExpanded);
  };

  return (
    ...
    <ExpandMore
      expand={isExpanded}
      onClick={toggleExpanded}
      aria-expanded={isExpanded}
    >
    ...
    <Collapse in={isExpanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
    ...
  );
};
```

If you don't want to use a new component you could store all the ids of the expanded cards in a state. Based on if the id is in the array the card will be expanded or collapsed.

```js
const [expandedIds, setExpandedIds] = useState([]);

const toggleExpanded = (id) => {
  setExpandedIds((prevExpandedIds) => {
    // if id is already in array remove
    if (prevExpandedIds.includes(id))
      return prevExpandedIds.filter((i) => i !== id);
    // else add to array
    return [...prevExpandedIds, id];
  });
};

return (
  ...
  <ExpandMore
    expand={expandedIds.includes(RecetasAll.id)}
    onClick={() => toggleExpanded(RecetasAll.id)}
    aria-expanded={expandedIds.includes(RecetasAll.id)}
  >
  ...
  <Collapse in={expandedIds.includes(RecetasAll.id)} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
  ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Testing the 2nd approach worked like a charm,also I learned a lot with your answer since Im kinda learning React.